# Given that the Moon affects tides and most of the human body is water, do tides affect people?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, estimation, tidal-effect

It is known that [the Moon causes tides](https://scijinks.gov/tides/). Given that the [human body is 60%-70% water](https://www.usgs.gov/special-topic/water-science-school/science/water-you-water-and-human-body?qt-science_center_objects=0#qt-science_center_objects), is there any research that shows that the tides affect humans in any tangible way?

If this is not the appropriate place to ask, then please let me know a more appropriate place to ask?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The gravitational attraction between two masses $m_1$, $m_2$ with distance $r$ can be calculated by
    $$F_G = G \frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2},$$
where $G$ is the gravitational constant. The average distance of the moon to earth is around $r^\prime=384402 km$ but because we are at the surface of the earth, we will gladly substract $6400km$ from it. Assuming you have a mass of $m_1=80kg$ and the moon's mass is $m_2=7.342 \cdot 10^{22}kg$ we arrive at
$$F_G = 2.744 mN.$$

This is about the same attraction you'd experience if you'd stand 2m in front of a space shuttle (thanks to Wolfram Alpha).

So the answer is: **No, you are not affected in any tangible way.**

Comment: Your answer should explain the relationship between the gravitational force and the tidal force.

Answer (score 4):

Tidal forces are not exclusive to water. Basically everything is affected by it as it's just an effect of gravity. But we are too small for it to be anything other than negligible.